# Реклама съедает память устройства

Tags: java, android, admob

Решил я попробовать добавить в одно своё `Activity` рекламу. Выбор упал на знаменитый *AdMob*. Всё сделал, реклама работает.

Прошло время, заметил, что приложение стало потреблять больше памяти. Методом поэтапного удаления выяснил, что источник проблем заключается как раз в рекламе, а точнее в нескольких строчках установки рекламы. Вот они сами:

```
AdView MyBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.MyBanner_id);

MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXX~YYY");

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("ZZZ")
                .build();
MyBanner.loadAd(adRequest);
```

`Profiler` говорит, что без этих строк `MEMORY` **35mb** , со строками **80mb**

**Вопрос:** как иметь рекламу и не тратить так много памяти?

Comment: Так что именно, инициализация или запрос съедает  память?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Надеюсь я правильно проверил: я запустил с интернетом и без. Разница около 20mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdMob использует WebView для загрузки объявлений. Это довольно ресурсоёмкий объект, который использует собственные библиотеки и подвержен сбоям. У вас нет никакого контроля над тем, как работает Admob SDK. Кроме того, использование памяти, вероятно, будет варьироваться в зависимости от типа объявления: тексты HTML и баннеры с изображениями и т.д.

Так же не стоит забывать про то, что нужно управлять жизненным циклом объявлений

```
 @Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();

    mAdView.resume();

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mAdView.pause();


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    mAdView.destroy();

}
```

Это должно помочь избежать утечек памяти.
С объёмом используемой памяти остаётся только смириться.
Можете почитать про [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) подробнее перейдя по ссылке.

Comment: Вебвью сам по себе огромная утечка памяти, которую никак не вылечить.

Comment: Все рекламные сервисы используют WebView для загрузки объявлений? Может быть вы можете порекомендовать какой-нибудь, по вашему мнению, менее затратный?

Comment: Я всегда использовал AdMob, опыта работы с другими сервисами нет.